# How to add an IFeature to the Map and zoom to it ?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcobjects, c#, feature-layer

I have an `ITable` i cast it to an `IFeatureLayerDefinition` after casting it to an `ILayer` then to an `IFeatureLayer`, then i used my `IFeatureLayerDefinition` to get only one `IFeature` using the `IFeatureLayerDefinition.DefinitionExpression` so when i add my `ILayer` to the Map and refresh it works but i couldn't zoom to it programmatically this is my code :

```
private void list_commune_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(table_commune==null) return;

    ILayer layer = (ILayer)table_commune;
    IFeatureLayer fl = (IFeatureLayer)layer;

    object selectedCommune = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem ;
    object code_commune = null;

    if (!this.commune_dic.ContainsKey(selectedCommune)) 
        return;
    else 
        code_commune = this.commune_dic[selectedCommune];

    IFeatureLayerDefinition featureLayerDef = (IFeatureLayerDefinition)fl;
    featureLayerDef.DefinitionExpression = "NUM_COMMUNE = " + (code_commune);

    Map.AddLayer(layer);
    Map.Extent = Map.get_Layer(0).AreaOfInterest;
    Map.Refresh();
}
```

And this how my IFeature looks like when i added it to the Map : 
[image: And this how my IFeature looks like when i added it to the Map]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i've just found a solution, 
I create an IFeatureCursor and an IFeature and called IFeatureLayer.Search() to get the IFeatureCursor then called ICursor.NextFeature() to get the IFeature then set the Map.Extent to IFeature.Extent and it did work :)

```
private void list_commune_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(table_commune==null) return;

    ILayer layer = (ILayer)table_commune;
    IFeatureLayer fl = (IFeatureLayer)layer;

    object selectedCommune = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedItem ;
    object code_commune = null;

    if (!this.commune_dic.ContainsKey(selectedCommune)) 
        return;
    else 
        code_commune = this.commune_dic[selectedCommune];

    IFeatureLayerDefinition featureLayerDef = (IFeatureLayerDefinition)fl;
    featureLayerDef.DefinitionExpression = "NUM_COMMUNE = " + (code_commune);


    IFeatureCursor cursor = fl.Search(null, false);
    IFeature feature = cursor.NextFeature();

    Map.AddLayer(layer);
    Map.Extent = feature.Extent;
    Map.Refresh();
}
```